# Can i use XULRunner to create executable that acts like a phonegap app (WebView and fullscreen?) on the desktop (Windows/Linux/OSX)?

Tags: webview, cross-browser, cross-platform, desktop-application, xulrunner

**Story:**
I have written a HTML Merge Compiler that can merge resource's/assets into one single HTML file (minify it to the max) and compiles Javascript with the google enclosure compiler. I have written this compiler to speed up loading and interpreting the code and to obfuscate the code to protect a little bit (script kiddie protection). Major reason was/is speed and to make it compact.

This is working OK with reliable results and i use this in PhoneGap applications/games. I have also written a javascript library that encapsulate all platforms that works with standard HTML/CSS without the need to change the code, it works also in the browser, with a touchscreen or without or on any device or operating system. Write once, publish many ;-). The idea around it is that is working always, always operate the same but can use device specific things when available but does never fail (when something is not there, for example a vibrate functionality).

Anyway, most frameworks (like PhoneGap) concentrate on Mobile Platforms but i want to port it also to desktop platforms like Windows, OSX and maybe Linux. For Windows I have wrote an Delphi Application that loads the HTML in a TEmbeddedWB object (is Internet Explorer actually) but the 'problem' is that it is only suitable to Windows and IE is not the fastest browser around, especially when it is embedded (do not why it is slower than the browser itself). For example, when i load the compiled code in Firefox and/or Google Chrome it is blazing fast (you do not notice it is javascript ;-)).

**EDIT:**
Pre release of IE10 for Windows 7 is just launched, installed it and lag is gone!
You can download it from here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35709

**Introduction to my question:**
I have tried XULRunner of Mozilla a long time ago but the first time was not a pleasure to me and also i tried it today again but can't get it to work. Get a parse error in the main xul file of the project, window is an undefined entity. ??? I create a sample project like: http://mdn.beonex.com/en/Getting_started_with_XULRunner.html

I do not know what to do about this error. Also i think documentation is not up-to-date? Most documentation is from around 2006.

**The question, what i want to know:**

- Before i am going to waste my time (see also introduction), is it
  possible to create frameless (full-screen) desktop executables with
  use of XULRunner like with PhoneGap?
- Is it possible to create cross-platform applications with XULRunner, i mean, does it really work seamless. Where can i find a ready-to-publish example of a XULRunner project and is it possible to load local HTML file(s) like in PhoneGap?
- It is possible and allowed to access external resources?

Long story, but maybe there is somebody that have tried this before and can lead me to choose the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

> is it possible to create frameless (full-screen) desktop executables with use of XULRunner like with PhoneGap?

Yes. You use [`disablechrome` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/window#a-disablechrome) to remove the window frame and [`sizemode="maximized"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/window#a-sizemode) to have it open full-screen. Alternatively you can use the [full-screen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.mozRequestFullScreen) if you want your application to run in a normal window and only switch to full-screen mode on request.

> Is it possible to create cross-platform applications with XULRunner

Yes. There are things like menus that work very differently on OS X but most of the time you don't need to care what operating system your application runs on (Windows, Linux and Mac OS X supported).

> Where can i find a ready-to-publish example of a XULRunner project

See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Getting_started_with_XULRunner) for a XULRunner application example. For "ready-to-publish" you would need an installer which doesn't come with the platform.

> is it possible to load local HTML file(s) like in PhoneGap?

Yes. The top-level window has to be XUL but you can use some very minimal code here - essentially a single [`<iframe flex="1"/>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/iframe). You can load HTML pages into that frame then.

> It is possible and allowed to access external resources?

Yes, XULRunner applications have full privileges and can access files on disk as well as web resources without any restrictions.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info. Found that documentation also. But another question, does have the embedded iframe restrictions? Is it possible to communicate with the iframe without destrictions? What can i do with the parse error in the main xul file of the project, window is an undefined entity. ??? Don't understand this error.

Comment: @Erwinus: It's up to you whether you want to restrict the embedded iframe. If it is local code then you probably want to use the `chrome://` protocol for it - meaning running it with full privileges. Remote code on the other hand should never be trusted.

Comment: `Where can i find a ready-to-publish example of a XULRunner project`
[Here](https://github.com/neam/webapp-xul-wrapper) is a ready-to-publish XUL app that does nothing but show html resources in a browser view. It comes with build scripts to create native installers and bundles a http server. It should be easy to make it full screen by following Wladimirs advice.